# Can I directly deploy generated docker image without pushing it to DockerHub?

Tags: docker, circleci-2.0

I don't want to push a docker build image to DockerHub. Is there any way to directly deploy a docker image from CircleCI to AWS/vps/vultr without having to push it to DockerHub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use docker save/load commands:

```sh
# save image to tar locally
docker save -o ./image.tar $IMAGEID
# copy to target host
scp ./image.tar user@host:~/
# load into target docker repo
ssh user@host "docker load -i ~/image.tar"
# tag the loaded target image
ssh user@host "docker tag $LOADED_IMAGE_ID myimage:latest"
```

PS: LOADED_IMAGE_ID can be retrieved in following way:

```
REMOTE_IMAGE_ID=`ssh user@host"docker load -i ~/image.tar" | grep -o "sha256:.*"`
```

Update:
You can gzip output to make it smaller. (Don't forget unzip the image archive before load)

```
docker save $IMAGEID | gzip > image.tar.gz
```

Comment: thanks but is there any other way as to upload 400mb image, it will take 1-2 minutes.

Comment: You can gzip output. Have a look at updated answer, please.

Comment: Alternatively you could enable compression on scp command. Something like this:
`scp -C ./image.tar user@host:~/`

Comment: yes that will work then we have first unzip file before loading via docker.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your own registry: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Edit: As i.bondarenko said, docker save/load are the better commands for your needs.

Comment: Docker export is used to persist a container (not an image). For docker image docker save is suitable. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: You are right. Save is the better command in this case. I will update my answer. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author of Dogger.

I made a blog post about it here, which allows just that: https://medium.com/@mathiaslykkegaardlorenzen/hosting-a-docker-app-without-pushing-an-image-d4503de37b89